# Student T distribution as a solution of a differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, probability, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-pde

From the links between probability theory and analysis, we know that lots of pdf usually represent a solution to a differential equation, e.g. the normal distribution is the solution to the heat equation. However, what can be said about the Student T distribution? To my best knowledge, there is no PDE or ODE that admits as a solution the function

$$
f(x)=\frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{\nu + 1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\nu \pi \sigma^2}\Gamma \left( \frac{\nu}{2}\right)} \left( 1 + \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{\nu\sigma^2} \right)^{-\frac{\nu + 1}{2}}
$$

Any toughts about this question would help me a lot! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pdf of the t-distribution is a solution to the following differential equation:
$$
{
{\begin{array}{l}\left(\nu +x^{2}\right)f'(x)+(\nu +1)xf(x)=0,\\
\\
\text{with }f(1)={\frac {\nu ^{\nu /2}(\nu +1)^{-{\frac {\nu }{2}}-{\frac {1}{2}}}}{B\left({\frac {\nu }{2}},{\frac {1}{2}}\right)}}\end{array}}}
$$
where $B(x,y)$ is a beta function.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you please post the reference in which you found it?

Comment: [here](https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9A%CE%B1%CF%84%CE%B1%CE%BD%CE%BF%CE%BC%CE%AE_t-Student#.CE.94.CE.B9.CE.B1.CF.86.CE.BF.CF.81.CE.B9.CE.BA.CE.AE_.CE.95.CE.BE.CE.AF.CF.83.CF.89.CF.83.CE.B7)

Comment: No reference even on the Greek wiki -_-'

Comment: Actually you can refer to the [Pearson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_distribution); the $t-$disrtibution belongs to the [Pearson type VII distribution](https://archive.org/stream/philtrans06851425/06851425#page/n6/mode/1up)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details!